# Why do I get "exc bad access" when trying to display city and state name in a UILabel in Swift?

Tags: swift, mapkit

Im not sure what Im doing wrong. I have this code below where I’m trying to display the city and state name in a `UILabel`. Xcode keeps crashing when it gets to the line `if let city = selectedPin!.locality`. Why does this happen?

```
var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil

@objc func saveNameToLabel(){

    let placemark = MKPlacemark()
    selectedPin = placemark

    if let city = selectedPin!.locality, //Here is where I get the Error Access
        let state = selectedPin!.administrativeArea {

        labelForCityAndState.text = "\(city) \(state)"
        print("display city and state in label")
    }
}
```

Comment: And, as Deryck said, if you’re going to unwrap with `if let`, you really should use `?` instead of `!` (e.g. `if let city = selectedPin?.locality, ...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re getting this error because `MKPlacemark` apparently expects you to supply a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to one of the `init` methods that have `coordinate` parameter. E.g.:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ..., longitude: ...)
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
```

One can imagine that the author of the `MKPlacemark` never contemplated someone creating a placemark that doesn’t actually represent some coordinate. Clearly, it would be nice if `MKPlacemark` handled this error more gracefully, but, alas, it doesn’t. You should feel free to [report feedback to Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) on this behavior, if you want.